# Emdeded resources with DevExpress WinForm

Tags: c#, dll, devexpress, assemblies

I am trying to create an exe with embedded resources. Everything works fine, but if the DevExpress.Utils.dll is not in the same folder like the .exe the application crashes!
Although all dll files are included as embedded resources and I reference to these.
The strange thing is it is only the DevExpress.Utils.dll.
Dlls that are not found I am loading with this:

```
[STAThread]
  static void Main()
  {
     AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomainOnAssemblyResolve;

      Application.EnableVisualStyles();
      Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
      Application.Run(new MyForm());
  }

  private static Assembly CurrentDomainOnAssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
  {
    // the ddls are in a lib folder.
     String resourceName = "MyApplication." + "lib." + new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll";

     using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
     {
        if (stream != null)
        {
           Byte[] assemblyData = new Byte[stream.Length];


           stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);


           return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
        }
     }
     return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who runs in this problem:

DevExpress: "CLR tries to verify the code in the Main method. Since the method contains DevExpress types, CLR tries to load a corresponding assembly that contains this type and fails because the assembly does not exist in the folder where the .exe file is."

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomainOnAssemblyResolve;

  Application.EnableVisualStyles();
  Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
  Application.Run(ReturnXtraForm());
}

private static Assembly CurrentDomainOnAssemblyResolve(object sender,   ResolveEventArgs args)
{
// the ddls are in a lib folder.
 String resourceName = "MyApplication." + "lib." + new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll";

 using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
 {
    if (stream != null)
    {
       Byte[] assemblyData = new Byte[stream.Length];


       stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);


       return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
    }
 }
 return null;
}

private static Form ReturnXtraForm() {
      DevExpress.Skins.SkinManager.EnableFormSkins();
      UserLookAndFeel.Default.SetSkinStyle("DevExpress Style");
      return new MyForm();
  }
```